# Where should function definitions be written in Allegro CL Free Express Edition 9.0?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, allegro-cl

Where should I write function definitions with `defun`? In debug window or in the editor? I have tried to write definitions in both places but am getting errors.

Comment: You should copy and paste the errors you are seeing, as well as your own input.

Comment: either place is OK. Your errors are unrelated to that.

Comment: Franz has a user forum for such questions. see http://franz.com/support/acl.forum.lhtml

Answer (score 2):

Franz also has a tutorial for the IDE, [Writing and Running Lisp Code in the IDE: a Tutorial](http://www.franz.com/support/tutorials/ide-used-for-lisp.htm), of which section 3 is *Using the IDE for Lisp once Allegro CL has started*, which says

> The Debug Window contains a Lisp Listener pane where Lisp expressions may be evaluated, and where printed output appears by default. You can evaluate expressions by typing them at the listener's prompt, and then pressing the Enter key. (The prompt is the string like "cg-user(1): " at the very end of the window's text.)

and

> While a listener is fine for entering short lisp expressions on the fly, you need to use an editor to write significant lisp code and to save it to disk. You can use the IDE Editor for this, or Emacs with our Emacs-Lisp Interface (ELI). The trade-off is that Emacs is a more powerful text editor, but in the IDE Editor you can apply many general IDE commands to symbols and forms in your code. Here we will be using the IDE Editor.

Which you should use depends on how much code you are writing.  However, if you've “tried to [write your code] in both places but errors are coming,” it's probably not an issue with *where* you're writing it, but in *what* code you're writing.  (If you have questions about the actual code you're writing, ask a separate question, and show your code, as well as the errors that you're getting.)